# For Loop in Python isn't working

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, variables, for-loop

```
 inputs = []
 iterations = int(input())
 for x in inputs:
     currentInput = input()
     inputs.append(currentInput)
     print(x)
```

That code isn't working. It is supposed to make more "currentInput" variables based on "iterations". Thank you soooo, much, as this has been bugging me.

Comment: It isn't very clear from your description what you want this code to do. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't working because it's not right.

Your for loop is going through each element in the list `inputs`. But `inputs` is an empty list; you haven't added anything to it so the for loop won't work. You must have meant

```
for x in range(iterations):
    currentInput=input()
    inputs.append(currentInput)
    print(currentInput)
```

Comment: That isn't what I wanted! I want it to act like a forEach!

Comment: What is the iterations variable for then?  From what I understand you want to take in an input 'iterations' number of times and add those to a list.

Comment: That is correct! But, what I want to do is that and then after, print them using x. I actually just had it but then my code messed up.

Comment: This can actually be done in one line using a list comprehension. `inputs = [input() for i in range(iterations)]`.

Comment: Oh. Well then just print `currentInput`

Comment: @CyberakaTHEGAMERCraft perhaps you should edit your question so it explains what you are actually trying to accomplish

Comment: @Natrocks, you helped me but I used a while loop!